# switchOff/ switchOn twilio not working as expected

Tags: javascript, video, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I wanted to detect switch off and switch on event on Twilio network bandwidth API. I am following this article (https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-bandwidth-profile-api).

This is my configuration for api.

```
  bandwidthProfile: {
          video: {
            mode: 'grid',
            trackSwitchOffMode: 'detected',
            maxSubscriptionBitrate: 2400000, // 2.4MB
            dominantSpeakerPriority: 'high',
            maxTracks: 3,
            renderDimensions: {
              high: { width: 1080, height: 720 },
              standard: { width: 640, height: 480 },
              low: { width: 160, height: 80 }
            }
          }
        },
```

I am getting isSwitchOff value false every time.

Thanks in advance

**Edit** This is the code where `isSwitchedOff` is used:

```js
const [isSwitchedOff, setIsSwitchedOff] = useState(track && track.isSwitchedOff);
useEffect(() => {
  setIsSwitchedOff(track && track.isSwitchedOff)
  if (track) {
    const handleSwitchedOff = () => setIsSwitchedOff(true)
    const handleSwitchedOn = () => setIsSwitchedOff(false)
    track.on("switchedOff", handleSwitchedOff)
    track.on("switchedOn", handleSwitchedOn)
    return () => {
      track.off("switchedOff", handleSwitchedOff);
      track.off("switchedOn", handleSwitchedOn);
    };
  }}, [track]);
```

Comment: How are you detecting the switch offs? Are you looking for `isSwitchOff` or [`isSwitchedOff`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-bandwidth-profile-api#programming-with-video-track-switch-offs)?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for isSwitchedOff. It's a typo in question but right in my code.

Comment: Ok, when are you calling on `isSwitchedOff`? What events are you listening to?

Comment: Yes i am calling isSwitchedOff

Comment: Can you share the full context, the function in which you are calling that? Please edit your question with the code.

Comment: This is my react code 

`const [isSwitchedOff, setIsSwitchedOff] = useState(
    track && track.isSwitchedOff
  );

  useEffect(() => {

    setIsSwitchedOff(track && track.isSwitchedOff)

    if (track) {
      const handleSwitchedOff = () => setIsSwitchedOff(true)
      const handleSwitchedOn = () => setIsSwitchedOff(false)
      track.on("switchedOff", handleSwitchedOff)
      track.on("switchedOn", handleSwitchedOn)
      return () => {
        track.off("switchedOff", handleSwitchedOff);
        track.off("switchedOn", handleSwitchedOn);
      };
    }
  }, [track]);`

Comment: So, you are saying that the tracks are always switched on? Is this a problem? How are you triggering the conditions for the track to be switched off?

Comment: I am following this repo.

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react

Comment: Are you saying that the tracks are always switched on? Is this a problem? How are you triggering the conditions for the track to be switched off?

Comment: I want to know if the video SwitchedOff by Twillio due to low bandwidth so I can show some message to other participants but I'm always getting isSwitchedOff false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228782/discussion-between-philnash-and-arsalan-subhan).